# How to get time in millisecond since epoch in python for a custom time?

Tags: python, time, epoch

I am trying to get the time in millisecond since epoch passed for a custom time.

I tried using the following code and was able to get the time in seconds since epoch passed.

```
dt = datetime(2022,5,1,0,0,1,100000)
print(dt)
endtime = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
endtime = endtime * 1000
print(endtime)
```

This however, stops at seconds and I get the value of 1651343401000 instead of 1651343401100.

Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it much too hard on yourself.
The [API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) already offers what you're looking for:

```
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 100000)
>>> 
>>> dt.timestamp()
1651388401.1
```

Feel free to pick out the integer and fractional parts of that, if you like.
Or scale the final component:

```
>>> millis = dt.microsecond / 1e3
>>> millis
100.0
```

---

As a separate matter,
you're probably better off
steering away from naïve stamps and preferring UTC.
Then "seconds since epoch" will have the conventional meaning.

```
>>> from datetime import timezone
>>> dt = datetime(2022, 5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 100_000, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
>>> dt.timestamp()
1651363201.1
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot! I was searching for this online. But couldn't find one. I am relatively new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get current time:

```
round(time.time() * 1000)
```

And use this for custom time:

```
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds() * 1000)
```

I hope it would help you